# Getting node attribute value and node value together

Tags: jquery, xml

Well I have this XML here,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE reviews SYSTEM "bookstore.dtd">

<bookstore>
<location>Port Credit</location>
<address intersection="Hurontario And Lakeshore"/>
<book id="1000">
    <title> Intro to C</title>
    <copies>5</copies>
    <author name="John Fingle"/>
    <author name="Carrie Dingle"/>
<price>20.95</price>
</book>
<book id="1001">
    <title>C for Rocket Scientists</title>
    <copies>3</copies>
    <author name="Robert Johnson"/>
    <author name="B. King"/>
<price>28.95</price>
</book>
<book id="1011">
    <title>Les Miserables</title>
    <copies>5</copies>
    <author name="Victor Hugo"/>
<price>24.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

I am trying to get the Book id's and their prices together by this,

```
$(xml).find("bookstore").each(function() {
    $(this).find("book").each(function() {
        $("#bookListDiv").html($(xml).find("price").text() + "<br />");
        $("#bookListDiv").html($(this).attr("id"));
    })
 });
```

Moreover I am trying to get the name & title together too using same thing. All it does is just gives a single result. Do I have to use a kind of loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use

```
$(xml).find("bookstore").each(function() {
    $(this).find("book").each(function() {
        $("#bookListDiv").append($(this).find("price").text() + "<br />");
        $("#bookListDiv").append($(this).attr("id"));
    })
 });


html() will replace your content inside div
```